# Basic Wordpress | How to create standardized, but editable fields in pages and posts

Tags: wordpress

This is probably an easy one, but I've been struggling to find the answer to this.  I would like to create a standard format Wordpress page for real estate listings.  Where I'm having trouble is with creating fields that can easily be edited from within the page for certain key features of each property listing.  For instance, a typical page would have a title, slideshow of photos, a paragraph of text describing the property, **but then** a bulleted list with standard items such as: MLS#, Sq. Ft., Beds, Baths, Garage, Neighborhood, Acreage, Type, Price, etc.  It would be ideal if these items were always displayed and you could just type in the associated information with each into a field box.

Does anyone have a suggestion or recommendation on a plugin for something like this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: My favourite is Meta Box: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-box/

Comment: I'd recommend advanced custom fields.  http://advancedcustomfields.com

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is an advanced custom field editor. There's an article from smashing magazine that teaches you how to create the layout.  You can find it at [Smashing Magazine](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/), and also there's a plugin at [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) which can help too.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite Custom Fields plugin is [Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/).